# How can I make a mesh see through in Maya?

Tags: maya

I am trying to make a see through sphere in maya, does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

Comment: enter wireframe mode

Answer (score 0):

Refer to  [Manual:](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/?guid=PC_Maya_Hotkeys)

Display Settings:

`4` = `Shading` > `Wireframe`

Painting Operations:

`Alt`+`a` = `Turn Show Wireframe on or off`

Comment: When i export that as an obj file, i need to maintain the transparancy? will this do that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "see-through". If you mean adjusting the transparency of an object, that object's material has that ability.

All standard materials in Maya (Lambert, Blinn, Phong, Surface Shader) have an Transparency attribute that will adjust the object's transparency/opacity.

When you save this as an OBJ, you can select to save the object's materials as well. When you import the OBJ file, the material will also import and keep the transparency.